# About the use of the past tense

Tags: american-english

I read a sentence:

> Roland was looking for Joe the whole day.

As far as I understand it, this is an illustration of something that happened in the past. Can I change "looked for" to "looking for" instead?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, "Roland was looking for Joe" is just as good (I would argue better) than "Roland looked for Joe."

Comment: Do you mean "Roland **was looked for** Joe..." or "Roland **looked for** Joe..."?

Comment: @EliHarold Without knowing the context, why do you think one is better than the other?

Comment: @gotube In the sentence we have we are talking about an action that occurred for a long period of time. It is my opinion that when talking about continuous events "Roland was looking for Joe" sounds better. If the action was "pressing a button" I believe "Roland pressed the button at 5:00pm" sounds better than "Roland was pressing the button at 5:00pm." It is a matter of preference, but I believe you may be able to see the appeal that I am talking about, but I know that specific context could call for one or the other, but without more information I cannot comment on that.

Comment: @EliHarold I was asking the OP. If you replace "looking for" with "looked for", the resulting sentence is "...was looked for..." which may or may not have been their intent.

Comment: @gotube In Chinese,   "Roland was looked for Joe..." and "Roland looked for Joe..." seem that there is no difference between the two expressions. So I can't understand. As far as the sentence itself is concerned, I think this sentence wants to express that in the past time yesterday, Roland spent a whole day looking for Joe.

Answer (score 2):

Both "Roland was looking for Joe the whole day" and "Roland looked for Joe the whole day" read as correct, but they have subtly different meanings.

"Was looking" is the past continuous tense. It describes an action that occurred in the past and continued to occur.

"Looked" is the simple past tense. It describes an action that occurred in the past.

There are some cases where only one or the other would be correct, for example if you are describing how the past action was in progress when something else happened, you have to use the past continuous:

Roland was looking for Joe when he was hit by a car

If an event is discrete and ended, you have to use the simple past tense:

Roland bought a book

In cases where either would be correct, like the above one, the past continuous puts a little more emphasis on the way the event took time. So in your example, "was looking" puts a little more emphasis on the fact that a whole day is a long time to look for someone.

Finally, I'd suggest "all day" would be more idiomatic than "the whole day", though I'm not sure if that's a US English thing or a general English thing.

Comment: Thanks，Nick . With your explanation, I think I fully understand its usage. And what I learned in school was a bit biased. Many usages are considered wrong, although teachers cannot clearly explain why. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Roland **was looking for** Joe the whole day.-past continuous tense

Roland **looked for** Joe the whole day.- simple past tense

Both are correct. They have different meanings.

Ronald was looking for - The action was not a complete one. It was continuing in the past. Ronald was in the middle of the action.

Ronald looked for - It was a complete action in the past. The action was finished. It was not continuing.